# How do I connect a binding to a (Winform) ComboBox control to get/set the selection in the control from the binding source?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, dataset

I have plumbed the deeps of my google-fu to find an answer.

First, I am not simply asking how to bind a combobox to a datasource.  It's a bit more than that unless I'm having a serious understanding gap.

On my Winform, I have a DataGridview on the left and on the right I have a panel with values from the selected row on the left.  One of those controls on the right is the ComboBox I'm having trouble with.  I have my bindingsource and dataview set up and the other controls on the right are working splendidly, except the ComboBox control.

The user, interacting with this ComboBox, should see values such as "Item ABC" and "Item EFG" and the value related to them might be 1234 and 5678.  If this was a fully unbound control I'd put an object array of items in.  Once I get it working, I'd load that from a different source.

But when I try to DataBindings.Add("??", dataview, "dataviewfield", ...) I can't get the proper value for "??".  Runtime debug shows that "SelectedItem.Value" would be the right option, but I get "not found" type exception when I use that.  I've tried "SelectedValue" as well, but that didn't work (debug show's it's null & throws no nulls allowed exception).

How can I get that value placed directly into the DataView via the Binding?

Setting the .DataSource simply loses the items and doesn't help at all.

How does one do this?  Short of making the ComboBox unbound totally, setting the selectedindex directly and capturing the value when the selected index changes changes - Just seems so clunky to have to do that.

-old programmer

Further Notes:  I edited to clarify the placement of the ComboBox.

I have made progress (naturally, only after asking a question does a new avenue pop into my head).  I got to thinking I might need a custom binding adapter so started googling that.  I found some samples doing what I want.

The foremost problem was I was not using assigning a datasource on the ComboBox, I was simply adding items.  When I created a two column dataset and a few rows (could have been anything I suppose) and set that and the two field names as the ComboBox's displaymember and valuemember did the SelectedValue start showing a value (instead of null all the time).

I think that was the problem.  The remaining issue is getting the left hand side to re-display/refresh after the change.

Comment: You have explained a lot but it is still not clear what's exact issue you are facing. It will help if you share the relevant code and explain how to reproduce the issue... `DataBindings.Add("??", dataview, "dataviewfield", ...)` it is not clear when this code is executed and why you have written this line of code... please add little bit crisp details along with relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

When loading the datasource for the DataGridView and the bindingsource, try making them share the same list:

```
BindingSource1.Datasource = dataset
DataGridView.Datasource = BindingSource1
```

This should mean that any changes to the data in the bindingsource will also update the DataGridView.

To edit the selected object then just handle the SelectionChanged event and set the BindingSource1.Position to the index of the selected object in the Datasource.

Comment: I'm thinking this response is working the wrong direction.  The combobox is on the dependent "form" (right panel).  I'm was able to get it to work, just a bit of difficulty refreshing the left once the change was made on the right (the events all seem to fire at wrong times).